# I'm converting seconds to hour and minutes using datetime in pandas, but it is showing with the date 1970. How do i remove date?

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to convert seconds to hour and minutes, but it is taking time with the date 1970. How do I fetch only time?

```
ageis_aht_percentile['aht_in_secs'] = pd.to_datetime(ageis_aht_percentile["aht_in_secs"], unit='s')
```

I want only time, not date. Since it is coming with the date, I'm not able to create a clear graph.

This is how my data is:

```
         aht_in_secs
count     5.000000
mean    907.200000
std     552.150976
min     292.000000
25%     406.000000
50%    1084.000000
75%    1135.000000
max    1619.000000
```

Please, someone, help me in converting aht_in_secs column to HH:MM:SS format

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(ageis_aht_percentile["aht_in_secs"], unit='s').dt.time`

Comment: I'm getting error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable

Comment: @GokkulKumar for which of the two suggestions are you getting the error?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, this is what you need.

```
ageis_aht_percentile['aht_in_secs'] = pd.to_datetime(ageis_aht_percentile["aht_in_secs"].round(), unit='s').dt.time
```

**Output** Showing bout intput & output as columns

```
        aht_in_secs     aht_in_secs3
count   5.000000        00:00:05
mean    907.200000      00:15:07
std     552.150976      00:09:12
min     292.000000      00:04:52
25%     406.000000      00:06:46
50%     1084.000000     00:18:04
75%     1135.000000     00:18:55
max     1619.000000     00:26:59
```